# R: Substitute values in a dataframe under conditions

Tags: r, function, dataframe, mean, substitution

I have got a dataframe made up by three columns (see example in the code). the first column contains categories (a), the second column the number of observations (b) and the third column the average value of these observations(c).

```
    #create a test df
    a<-factor(c("aaa","aaa","aaa","ddd","eee","ddd","aaa","ddd"))
    b<-c(3,4,1,3,5,7,3,2)
    c<-c(1,2,NA,4,5,6,7,NA)
    df.abc<-data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
    df.abc
```

If the number of observations was 1 or 2 the entries where marked as missing values (NA).

So the aim of my function is to substitute theses missing values by the mean value of each category.

I took me while but I got a function working, that substitutes all the missing values for one category (in case that the observation was 1). It looks like this:

```
    #function to substitue the missing values in row c by their means 
    #according to their categories
    function.abc<-function(x){
        ifelse(
            (df.abc[,1]==x)&(df.abc[,2]==1),
            mean(df.abc$c[df.abc$a ==x],na.rm=TRUE),
            df.abc[,3]
        )
    }
```

Testing this function:

```
    #test the function for the category "ccc"
    function.abc("aaa")
```

It works quite well (but is only the mean rather than the average mean) The output is:

[1] 1.000000 2.000000 3.333333 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000       NA

Now my problem is, that i have quite a lot of categories (n=32) and I tried to apply this function over a vector containing my categories. A simpe example in this case would be:

```
    #test the function for a testvector
    test.vector<-c("aaa","ddd")
    function.abc(test.vector)
```

the output is:

[1] 1.0 2.0 4.5 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0  NA

So obviously this won't work out...

Can anybody help me to rearrange the function? I'm quite new to programming and it is still a big challenge for me to design short and goodworking functions...

**Edit:**

I would like the output to be:
[1] 1.000000 2.000000 3.20000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 5.000000

so that the average of group aaa (3.20000) substitutes the NA value in aaa and the average of group ddd (5.0000000) substitutes the NA in ddd...

Comment: It is not clear what you want to be returned for the last case.

Comment: He would want `[1] 1.000000 2.000000 3.333333 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 5.00000` I believe.

Comment: I do not think either of the offered answers are correct given the statement of the problem. If three items are in category "aaa" with values `=c(1,2,7)`, with counts `=c(3,4,3)`,  then the weighted mean is not 3.3333, is rather 3.2. If my understanding of the problem statement is wrong then perhaps the question could be amended to clarify why the counts are not to be used in calculating the mean?

Comment: @SeñorO & Dwin The question wasn't a 100 clear so I edited it above. Dwin was right that acutally I calculated only the mean not the average mean. He got the question right and his solution worked out very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with multiple columns at once within a category you will need to use something that splits the dataframe and then works on the components. The `lapply( split(df, fac), function(x) {...})` paradigm works well for this. Or you can use `transform` or the `plyr` package.

```
> lapply( split( df.abc, df.abc$a), 
               function(dfrm) { dfrm[is.na(dfrm$c), "c"] <- 
                  weighted.mean(dfrm[!is.na(dfrm$c) , "c"], dfrm[!is.na(dfrm$c), "b"])
                         dfrm} )  
                # need to evaluate dfrm in order to return the full value.
$aaa
    a b   c
1 aaa 3 1.0
2 aaa 4 2.0
3 aaa 1 3.2
7 aaa 3 7.0

$ddd
    a b   c
4 ddd 3 4.0
6 ddd 7 6.0
8 ddd 2 5.4

$eee
    a b c
5 eee 5 5
```

You can then `rbind` them using `do.call:

```
 do.call( rbind, lapply( split( df.abc, df.abc$a), 
          function(dfrm) { dfrm[is.na(dfrm$c), "c"] <-
                 weighted.mean(dfrm[!is.na(dfrm$c) , "c"], dfrm[!is.na(dfrm$c), "b"])
                   dfrm} ) )
        a b   c
aaa.1 aaa 3 1.0
aaa.2 aaa 4 2.0
aaa.3 aaa 1 3.2
aaa.7 aaa 3 7.0
ddd.4 ddd 3 4.0
ddd.6 ddd 7 6.0
ddd.8 ddd 2 5.4
eee   eee 5 5.0
```

Comment: worked out for me. Didn't even consider splitting it first but this makes totally sense. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if you mean to include all such rows, you can use %in%.

```
function.abc<-function(x){
  ifelse(
    (df.abc[,1] %in% x)&(df.abc[,2]==1),
    mean(df.abc$c[df.abc$a %in% x],na.rm=TRUE),
    df.abc[,3]
  )
}

> function.abc("aaa")
[1] 1.000000 2.000000 3.333333 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000       NA

> test.vector<-c("aaa","ddd")
> function.abc(test.vector)
[1]  1  2  4  4  5  6  7 NA
```

The last element is NA because column 'b' is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

`CatMeans <- tapply(df.abc$c, df.abc$a, function(x) mean(x, na.rm==T))` will get you means by category.

```
     aaa      ddd      eee 
3.333333 5.000000 5.000000
```

So doing it for all the all of them:

```
> CatMeans <- tapply(df.abc$c, df.abc$a, function(x) mean(x, na.rm==T))
> ifelse(is.na(df.abc$c), CatMeans[df.abc$a], df.abc$c)
[1] 1.000000 2.000000 3.333333 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 5.000000
```

You can make that into a function I'm sure. If you only want `"aaa"` and `"ddd"`, then you could have `ifelse(is.na(df.abc$c) & df.abc$a %in% c("aaa","ddd"),...`